# How can I make kml data look like google maps?

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-earth, arcgis, shapefile

I have a program that generates a .shp file, and exports this as a kml file. I would like to be able to display my output using the standard google map 'map' style (gray background, yellow streets, etc) in google earth, or in the google earth api.

Is there a style guide or method that I should be using?

Any thoughts appreciated - I wasn't sure how to structure this question.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an ArcGIS style that will mimic the Google roads style.
http://conversationswithmyself.com/181/

Comment: Any chance of permalink? (now gives 404)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can load KML files into Google Maps using the API:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html#XML_Overlays

It'll certainly look like Google Maps then :-)

Doesn't help you much if you absolutely need the data visualised inside Google Earth though.

Comment: Thanks, Tom, but how does it look the same? In the example (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/examples/geoxml-kml.html) these are just randomly colored lines overlaid on the existing map. I want the kml that I load in, to look like an existing google map.

Comment: Errrr... what's in your KML file?

Comment: Nothing special - just a .shp polyline road network I generated (within ArcGIS). I could manually identify what all the colors and line thicknesses are in google maps and apply those settings to my data; but I wanted to see if it was defined anywhere.

Comment: Sounds like that's what you might end up having to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can define styles in the KML and then apply them to the lines. I don't think there's any predefined styles that look like roads in google maps.

If you define the appearance in ArcGIS before exporting to KML, doesn't that set the appearance in Google Earth?

Comment: Yes - I just wasn't sure what settings to choose in ArcGIS